# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'texture')

Tags: javascript, oop, phaser-framework

```
preload() {
    // prelaoding atlas png and json and anim json
    this.load.atlas('character','./Assets/Sprites/character_atlas.png','./Assets/Sprites/character_atlas.json');
    this.load.animation('character_anims','./Assets/Sprites/character_anim.json');
}


create(){
    // assigning player object to a physic
    this.player = new Phaser.Physics.Matter.Sprite(this.matter.world,0,0,'character','male_1');
    // printing sprite onto screen
    this.add.existing(this.player);
    // assigning keyboard inputs to variables
    this.inputKeys = this.input.keyboard.addKeys({
        up: Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.UP,
        down: Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.DOWN,
        left: Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.LEFT,
        right: Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.RIGHT,
    })
    console.log(this.player);
}

update(){
    this.player.anims.play('walking_right')
```

Why is `this.player.anims` undefined? Doesn't `this.load.animation` create `this.player.anims`?

Inspector showing that anims has been initialized:

[image: Inspector showing that anims has been initialized]

Comment: What this.matter used in player creation ?

Comment: https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Matter.Sprite.html hello Ptit! here's the documentation

Comment: What I was meaning is that this.matter does not seems initialised

Comment: OHHHHHH, okay... might be a plugin installation issue, thanks will look into it!

edit: it does not seem to be the problem with this.matter.world as it is predefined in Phaser.